# Python Kivy/Pyjnius android NotificationListenerService

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius, notification-listener

I want to create an application for android with kivy in python, which Listens for notification.

I created a notification_listener.py:

```
from kivy import platform


if platform == "android":
    from jnius import autoclass, cast, PythonJavaClass, java_method
    from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread


    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")

    Activity = autoclass("android.app.Activity")
    Context = autoclass("android.content.Context")
    NotificationListenerService = autoclass("android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService")
    StatusBarNotification = autoclass("android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification")
    Log = autoclass("android.util.Log")
    Toast = autoclass("android.widget.Toast")

    String = autoclass("java.lang.string")
    CharSequence = autoclass("java.lang.CharSequence")

    activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
    currentActivity = cast(Activity, activity)
    context = cast(Context, currentActivity.getApplicationContext())


    class NotificationListener(PythonJavaClass):
        __javaclass__ = "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"
        __javacontext__ = "app"

        @java_method("()V")
        def onCreate(self):
            super(NotificationListener, self).onCreate()

            text = cast(CharSequence, String("Listener started..."))
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.show()

        @java_method("(Landroid/service/notification/StatusBarNotification)V")
        def onNotificationPosted(self, sbn):
            notification = cast(StatusBarNotification, sbn)
            extras = notification.getNotification().extras

            tag = String("Notification recived")
            msg_title = String("title: %s" % (extras.getString("android.title")))
            msg_text = String("text: %s" % (extras.getString("android.text")))

            Log.v(tag, msg_title)
            Log.v(tag, msg_text)

            text = cast(CharSequence, String("Notification recieved..."))
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.show()
```

but how do I have to add the  to the AndroidManifest.xml?
if I would do it in Java, the following code would be correct but its a python file, so how do I have to implement it?

```
<service name=".NotificationListener"
    android:label="notification_listener"
    android:permissions="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I made it work, so I am writing here about my experience.

Buildozer does not provide any options for registering a service with permissions and an intent-filter. However, you can customize AndroidManifest.xml from the template file which is located in your .buildozer directory.

```
/your/project/home/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/yourapp__armeabi-v7a/templates/AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml
```

You can insert the xml block between "end-if" and "if" so that it won't be changed by the buildozer.spec settings.

Next thing you need to make is a java class file. Unfortunately, python class cannot be bound to NotificationListeners, so you need to manually copy a java class that receives StatusBarNotifications.

The path is going to be:

```
/your/project/home/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/yourapp__armeabi-v7a/src/main/java/your/app/domain/NotificationListener.java
```

With the java class, you can broadcast the StatusBarNotification to the python side,`getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);`, and p4a's android.broadcast.BroadcastReceiver will receive the object on main.py.

Java class

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("sbn",sbn);
        Intent intent = new Intent("action_name_matches_with_java_side");
        intent.putExtra("sbn",sbn);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("KIVYAPP","Notification broadcasting prohibited");
    }
}
```

main.py

```
class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ...
        self.br = BroadcastReceiver(self.onReceive,actions=["action_name_matches_with_java_side"])
        self.br.start()
        ...

    def onReceive(self, context, intent):
        bundle = cast(Bundle, intent.getExtras())
        sbn = cast(StatusBarNotification,bundle.getParcelable("sbn"))
        ...
```